# material ui SelectField how to change width of Menu

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

can someone help me?
I have a SelectField with fullWidth={true}. But, when i have opened my options, the width of popover is more than width of SelectField. I found that width is added in Menu( if autoWidth is true, by default autoWidth is true). Is it possibility to change Menu's autoWidth from SelectField ?

Comment: The reported issue [#3808](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/3808) addresses a highly-related problem. I believe the bug will be gone soon in the next release. BTW I tried v0.14.4 as prompted in the report and this version is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is fixed in the current version - beta.1. And now you have the option to change it's width. You can check an example in the docs.
http://www.material-ui.com/v0.15.0-beta.1/#/components/select-field